# Behavior when opening file in truncate mode

Tags: c++, file-io, truncate

I'm working on file IO using C file descriptors. The problem is that I'm trying to create a generalized class which can accommodate the following sequence of events:

1. An existing text file in truncate mode (i.e. clear its current contents).
2. Text is written to this file
3. The just-written text is cleared.
4. New text is written to the file thereafter.

A simplified recreation of the problem is coded below:

```
//1.
int fd = open("/path/to_file/file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);

//2.
const char* text = "12345";
write(fd, static_cast<const void*>(text), 5);

//3.
ftruncate(fd, 0);

//4.
const char* new_text = "678";
write(fd, static_cast<const void*>(new_text), 3);
```

The output is that the file has 5 `\0` at the start, followed by the string `678`, so it looks like `\0\0\0\0\0678`.

It appears that `ftruncate` thinks I'm actually trying to extend the file by 5 bytes, as described here: https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate

> If the file previously was larger than this size, the extra data is lost. If the file previously was shorter, it is extended, and the extended part reads as null bytes ('\0').

But if I open the file using the `O_APPEND` flag, then everything works fine. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Also from `man ftruncate`: "*The file offset is not changed.*"

Comment: I don't understand how the offset problem is fixed when I open in append mode --> add more text --> clear everything --> add new text. This works fine without changing the file pointer.

Comment: Append-Mode does not allow seeking around inside the file. So in this mode the offet seems to get adjusted automagically to fulfill the latter constrain.

Comment: There is no language C/C++! The two **different** languages C and C++ have different ways to access files. You apparently use the C way (actually  POSIX functions, not C standard) in C++ code. So this is not C code.

Answer (score 4):

This is what your code is doing, step-by-step:

```
//1.
int fd = open("/path/to_file/new.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
```

File is created or truncated, size is zero, current offset of the open file descriptor is 0.

```
//2.
const char* text = "12345";
write(fd, static_cast<const void*>(text), 5);
```

The characters `12345` are written to the file, current offset is 5

```
//3.
ftruncate(fd, 0);
```

The length of the file is now zero.  **The current offset of the open file descriptor is 5.**

```
//4.
const char* new_text = "678";
write(fd, static_cast<const void*>(new_text), 3);
```

The characters `678` are written to the file **starting at the current offset of 5**.

Comment: So how do I fix it? I tried calling `lseek(fd, -5, SEEK_CUR);` or `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);` after calling `ftruncate`, but the problem persists. Also, why doesn't it happen when I open the file in append mode, write some more text to it, clear it, and then again write text to it? Going by your logic, this problem should happen then as well.

Comment: @Ali250: "*I tried calling [...] `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);` after calling `ftruncate`*" Are you sure  the call to `lseek()` didn't fail?

Comment: @Ali250 You're not checking *any* return values.  You need to check every one.

Comment: My bad. I was retrying on the same corrupted txt file. Apparently the truncate flag doesn't clear that sort of file. When I created the file anew it worked. Thanks.